# TeamCity File Content Replacer : string index out of range

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.1

I am trying to use TeamCity File Content Replacer build feature to replace certain keys in my App.config file (.NET console project).
As mentioned in [official documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/File+Content+Replacer) i have specified

**Process File** : *File which i would like to make replacements in*
**Find what** :   *RegEx which denotes the text i would like to replace*
**Replace With** : *TeamCity variable with which i like to replace text*

Everything works fine if **Replace With** text is short enough , for example ***dummyText*** works however things go wrong with lengthier values like `\\Server675X\Shared\Artifactory\` , the error message received in build logs is as follows :

```
[File Content Replacer] Applying replacement "\\Server675X\Shared\Artifactory\" to lines matched by pattern "(?<=key="MappingFileLocation" value=").*(?="\/>)" in the files matched by wildcard: **/SolutionName/App.config...

[File Content Replacer] Error replacing "(?<=key="MappingFileLocation" value=").*(?="\/>)" with "\\Server675X\Shared\Artifactory\": string index out of range: 32. Check your settings.

[File Content Replacer] Error replacing file contents: string index out of range: 32
```

I can see that 32 is exactly the length of replacement string, *question is what setting do i need to check/modify to make this replacement possible* ?

PS : I am using TeamCity Enterprise 9.1.7 (build 37573)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to the problem, the error message is very misleading the actual problem lies in escaping backslash

using `\\Server675X\Shared\Artifactory\` gives an error

> Error replacing file contents: string index out of range: 32

however when we use `\\\\Server675X\\Shared\\Artifactory\\` there is no error, notice how we escaped backslash.

It would have been better to receive a relevant error message saying *un-escaped character found* or something along these lines.

Hope this helps someone !